# Immigrate to file-per-table mode in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, windows

I have 20 MySQL databases and in each there are about 20 tables. All the data is saved in a file called ibData1. Now I discovered about the file per table mode but if I change the value in the my.ini file what would happen?

How can I immigrate to file-per-table mode and change all the data structure?

I prefer to have a directory for each Database where each table is saved in a different file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so funny. Yesterday, someone asked how to do the opposite and I answered that question : [Migrate from innodb_file_per_table to off in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61116/migrate-from-innodb-file-per-table-to-off-in-mysql/61123#61123)

Here the steps for what you want

## STEP #1

Set innodb_file_per_table to 0 in `my.ini`

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table = 1
```

## STEP #2

Login in Command Prompt in Administrator mode and run

```
C:\> net stop mysql
C:\> net start mysql
```

## STEP #3

Convert every InnoDB table to InnoDB again

```
set MYSQLUSER=root
set MYSQLPASS=rootpass
mysql -u%MYSQLUSER% -p%MYSQLPASS% -ANe"SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ' ENGINE=InnoDB;') FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB';" > C:\ConvertInnoDBToInnoDB.sql
notepad C:\ConvertInnoDBToInnoDB.sql
```

Once you view the script and are satisfied, login to mysql and run this

```
mysql> source C:\ConvertInnoDBToInnoDB.sql
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: This method seems incomplete. I need to keep the big ibdata1, cause moving it outof the way and having it replaced with a blank ibdata1/iblog causes "table not found" errors, as the metadata is still in the old ibdata1 you used to move your data out to the files. You've got a more complete method in another post and should probably augment this answer with these caveats.