# How can I determine which Innodb table is being written?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5

I am running Mysql 5.5.

I have about 100 Innodb tables spread over 10 DB's (mostly wordpress sites) and I am recently seeing a lot more disk IO than I have been, without any increase in traffic. The disk IO is from mysqld, and in monitoring mysqld, I am seeing what seem to me to be a lot of Innodb writes and specifically, I am seeing a lot of activity in the `Innodb_rows_updated` status variable that I can't easily explain.

Is there a way that I can determine which of the ~100 Innodb tables is having those rows updated?

Comment: Wouldn't you just use `performance_schema` for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SINGLE DATABASE

```
DATABASE_TO_VIEW=mydb
cd /var/lib/mysql/$(DATABASE_TO_VIEW)
watch "ls -lt | grep ibd$ | head -20"
```

If you want just the table names

```
DATABASE_TO_VIEW=mydb
cd /var/lib/mysql/$(DATABASE_TO_VIEW)
watch "ls -lt | grep ibd$ | head -20 | awk '{print $9}' | sed 's/\.ibd//'"
```

## MULTIPLE DATABASES

Create a script called `/root/InnoDBChanges.sh` with these lines

```
DATADIR=/var/lib/mysql
IBD1=/tmp/InnoDBFiles.txt
IBD2=/tmp/InnoDBFiles.srt
echo -n > ${IBD1}
cd ${DATADIR}
for DB in `ls -l | grep ^drw | awk '{print $9}' | grep -v mysql | grep -v performance_schema`
do
    FLDR=${DATADIR}/${DB}
    ls -l --time-style="+%s %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" ${FLDR}/*.ibd|awk '{print $6,$7,$8,$9}' >> ${IBD1}
done
sort -nr < ${IBD1} > ${IBD2}
head -32 ${IBD2} | awk '{print $2,$3,$4}'
```

Then, you can monitor all the databases for changes at the same time

```
chmod +x /root/InnoDBChanges.sh
watch -n 5 /root/InnoDBChanges.sh
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

## CAVEAT

If [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) is disabled, this will not work for you.

You will have to extract the tables from ibdata1. Then, you can try my solution.

## STEP #1

Set innodb_file_per_table to 1 in /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table = 1
```

## STEP #2

```
service mysql restart
```

## STEP #3

Convert every InnoDB table to InnoDB again

```
echo "SET SQL_LOG_BIN = 0;" > /root/ConvertInnoDBToInnoDB.sql
MYSQL_CONN="-u... -p..."
SQL="SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' ENGINE=InnoDB;')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB'"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -AN -e"${SQL}" >> /root/ConvertInnoDBToInnoDB.sql
less /root/ConvertInnoDBToInnoDB.sql
```

Once you view he script and are satisfied, login to mysql and run this

```
mysql> source /root/ConvertInnoDBToInnoDB.sql
```

Comment: hi, thanks. 2 things: 1. i have about 10 different DB's that i need to check on - the innodb tables are spread amongst them. 2. i get no output from the watch command. what is the "grep ibd$" for? - none of the tables have ibd as part of their filename.

Comment: Please run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table';`. What is it ???

Comment: `.ibd` is the file extension of the physical file for any InnoDB table, provided you have innodb_file_per_table enabled.

Comment: innodb_file_per_table OFF - can i turn it on on a production DB without messing things up?

Comment: I have bad news for you. All the InnoDB data and index pages are inside `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1`. My answer can only help if that is enabled and all the tables are extracted from it.

Comment: Got that. what will happen if i change that variable to ON and restart the server (i assume that is not a dynamic variable that i can change on the fly). ibdata1 = 202M

Comment: Nothing. It will let new tables be created in a separate file. All other tables are still inside ibdata1. See my post http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61116/migrate-from-innodb-file-per-table-to-off-in-mysql/61123#61123 on how to extract the files from ibdata1. The post tells you how to push all InnoDB tables inside ibdata1. Just set it to 1 any do the same thing and it will extract all the InnoDB tables. Be careful, you might neede some downtime for this one (depending on how much data you have).

Comment: Yup. Just fixed it. Thanks. I went back to my old post. and fixed it there as well.

Comment: ok, 202M of data in ibdata1. 100 lines (100 innodb tables) in ConvertInnoDBToInnoDB.sql. i really want to just run it but this is a production db. it's on a fast VPS with an SSD drive. do you think it's safe to run without doing a scheduled downtime and freaking out half a dozen fairly active bloggers?

Comment: Please go to my post http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8661/mysql-workbench-database-sizes/8662#8662 and run the first query. How much InnoDB data does it report ?

Comment: it says 0.085 GB

Comment: That's about 85M. You could probably do it fast, but someone will notice. Wait until activity dies down. Then go for it...

Comment: Rolando: thank you for the care, generosity, and amazing thoroughness of this answer. I just ran step #3 and I can now see which tables (there are 2 of them) are being modified constantly. Should make it relatively easy to track down what's causing it and fix it. A million thanks.