# mysqld is generating a lot of disk IO writes. How can I figure out why?

Tags: mysql

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server running half a dozen wordpress sites. Total traffic to the server is on the order of 30k page views a day.

Over the past couple months, with page views and network traffic roughly flat, my disk I/O has been trending up significantly. It has doubled over the past month. When I run iotop, I can see that mysqld (v. 5.5) is constantly writing to disk at a rate of around 5MB per minute. I can't think of anything happening on any of the sites that would generate so much writing.

I have spent a lot of time reading mysql tuning tutorials and adjusting variables (mostly to do with tmp table size, and query cache parameters) and nothing I have tried has made any difference. My current guess is that there is probably a bad query in one of the wordpress plugins in use. But there are a lot of plugins spread over half a dozen wordpress installs and I don't know where to look.

Is there some way that I can pinpoint what exactly is causing mysqld to be writing to the disk so much?

**UPDATE** : This question was explored in better detail and answered thoroughly [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89485/how-can-i-determine-which-innodb-table-is-being-written).

Comment: I would appreciate if whoever downvoted my question would leave a comment saying why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was explored in better detail and answered thoroughly [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89485/how-can-i-determine-which-innodb-table-is-being-written).

Comment: The link does not work :(

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas off the top of my head.

1. [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/) - a top clone of MySQL
2. [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) - a python top-like program specifically for io

Comment: thanks, i mentioned using iotop in my question - that's how i know that it is mysqld that is doing the disk io. i didn't mention it but i am also already using mytop (which is a very useful suggestion). if i am currently right about what is causing the io, the queries go by so fast that mytop doesn't catch them. but it is a great little utility.

Comment: re: iotop, ya, I saw that after I posted. Didn't read carefully before answering. re: mytop: -s or -delay seconds
How long between display refreshes. Default: 5

Comment: changed it to 1 and saw some things i wasn't seeing with 5, but still no smoking gun. one thing i saw might have led me in the right direction. i'll find out early tomorrow morning when i can delete a bunch of records in a bloated table.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the mysql processlist. mysql -p -e "show processlist". Or even a "show full processlist". It will give you a list of currently running queries.

Comment: thanks. unfortunately whatever is causing mysqld to write must be a very quick query and it doesn't linger in the process list. right now i am thinking it might be a query that is fast but causes a large tmp table write over and over with each request on one of the wordpress sites. if/when i confirm, i'll write up the answer.