# Why are tiny Innodb row updates causing so much disk IO?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5

This is a followup question to my earlier [How can I determine which Innodb table is being written?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89485/how-can-i-determine-which-innodb-table-is-being-written)

Using the accepted answer from the above-referenced question I was able to determine which (two) of a hundred Innodb tables were being constantly updated on my server. Using some trial and error, I was able to determine which specific rows in those tables were being updated.

The rows are essentially counters that are updating and updates are happening about 1/s (I ran a query that counted 54 updates in 60 seconds). The rows are tiny with 4 columns: `BIGINT, VARCHAR, LONGTEXT, VARCHAR`. The value in the `LONGTEXT` column of the row in question is just a 10-character string and that is the column that is being updated.

I ran a query that calculated the change in `Innodb_data_written` over 60 seconds and ran it several times. It ranged from 4.5 to 5.5 MB over 60 seconds. When I turned off the process that is responsible for the 1-character row updates, the change in `Innodb_data_written` over 60 seconds went down to .03 MB, so it definitely seems to be these tiny row updates that are responsible for the ~ 5MB per minute of Innodb disk IO.

The `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is ample and the Innodb buffer use percentage is around 30%.

So, the question is, how are a couple of 1/s row updates that are only changing 1 character in a tiny row generating ~ 5MB per minute of Innodb disk IO?

Comment: Can you convert the text column to `VARCHAR`?

Comment: No, I can't change the structure at all because it is a "mutt" wordpress table (wp_options) that gets used for all kinds of different data by different wordpress processes.

Comment: What does the update query look like, and what are the indexes on that table?

Answer (score 1):

Any UPDATE to a row requires the following (sooner or later):

- Read the 16KB block containing the row (unless cached in the buffer pool)
- Write the block back to disk (or cache it a long time)
- The "doublebuffer" is written once per transaction
- Do one write to the InnoDB log for transactional integrity.  (The
  details here depend on various settings and whether you wrap things
  in BEGIN..COMMIT.)
  Since you say the buffer_pool is big enough (apparently for the entire table and any secondary indexes?), the first two items will not tally many IOPs.

But that was not your question.

The actual I/O (pages) related to the buffer_pool is (Innodb_buffer_pool_reads + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed)

You will probably find this very low because of good caching:
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads / Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests